# Interfaces and outsourcing

Tags: php, class, interface

I probably don't understand something very basic.

Tim is making a hypothetical application that uses Sessions, he is lazy and wants to use existing solutions instead of making his own.
He discovers 2 developers, John and Fabien, who have exacly what he needs (but are not aware of each other):

Fabien, who created 2 classes and 1 interface

```
namespace Fabien;
interface SessionStorageInterface {
   public function set($key, $val); 
   public function get($key);
}
class Storage implements SessionStorageInterface {
   ...
}
class Session {
    public function __construct(SessionStorageInterface $storage){
        ...
    }
}
```

And John, who created 1 class and 1 interface that matches the interface created by Fabien

```
namespace John;
interface SessionStorageInterface {
   public function set($key, $val); 
   public function get($key);
}
class Storage implements SessionStorageInterface {
   ...
}
```

Tim thinks that John's Storage class is vastly superior to the one made by Fabien and wants to use it with the Session class

```
$storage = new John\Storage;
$session = new Fabien\Session($storage);
```

But this does not work, as Fabiens Session class only accepts classes that implement Fabien\SessionStorageInterface.

How can Tim use the Session class provided by Fabien in combination with the Storage class created by John?

Comment: It would work if the Session class didn't use type hinting.

Comment: @redreggae The Session class construct is partially based on the one in the symfony framework, and sadly it does use type hinting.

Comment: This really does read like a homework exercise

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you, I did my best to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a bit of glue-code between the two interfaces/implementations.
Define a class that implements the interface (A) you need but internally delegates method calls to an instance of the class (B) you want. So, your mediating [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) instance *is* an A but *has* an B.

```
<?php
namespace Fabien {
    interface SessionStorageInterface {
       public function set($key, $val); 
       public function get($key);
    }

    class Storage implements SessionStorageInterface {
        public function set($key, $val) { 
            echo 'enter ', __METHOD__, "\r\n";
            $this->stg[$key] = $val;
        }
        public function get($key) {
            echo 'enter ', __METHOD__, "\r\n";
            return $this->stg[$key];
        }
    }

    class Session {
        public function __construct(SessionStorageInterface $storage){
            echo 'enter ', __METHOD__, "\r\n";
            $storage->set('foo', 'bar');
            echo 'foo=', $storage->get('foo'), "\r\n";
        }
    }
}


namespace John {
    interface SessionStorageInterface {
       public function set($key, $val); 
       public function get($key);
    }
    class Storage implements SessionStorageInterface {
      public function set($key, $val) { 
            echo 'enter ', __METHOD__, "\r\n";
            $this->stg[$key] = $val;
        }
        public function get($key) {
            echo 'enter ', __METHOD__, "\r\n";
            return $this->stg[$key];
        } 
    }
}

namespace Demo {
    class StorageAdapter implements \Fabien\SessionStorageInterface {
        protected $storageJohn = null;

        public function __construct(\John\SessionStorageInterface $stg) {
            $this->storageJohn = $stg;
        }

        public function set($key, $val) { 
            echo 'enter ', __METHOD__, "\r\n";
            $this->storageJohn->set($key, $val);
        }

        public function get($key) {
            echo 'enter ', __METHOD__, "\r\n";
            $this->storageJohn->get($key);
        } 

    }


    function demo() {
        echo 'enter ', __METHOD__, "\r\n";
        $stg = new \John\Storage;
        $session = new \Fabien\Session( new StorageAdapter($stg) );
    }
    demo();
}
```

Comment: Great idea! The only drawback I can imagine is having to type out all the functions if there are a lot of them. P.S. Your "mediator" class uses the "decorator" pattern as far as I know.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen I think it's more like an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Comment: @Yoshi reading the wiki page it seems the Adapter pattern was created to solve the problem that I described, thank you for linking to it!

Answer (score 0):

They don't.

As in probably most other programming languages they have to implement the same interface (same !== same signature).

They also learn the one class/interface per file rule to make things easy for someone that would like to hack something out of their code.

Comment: I skipped the one class per file rule for the sake of simplifying the example as it is not related to the question

Comment: Sorry, I phrased my idea poorly. The idea is to make life easy for someone hacking their code.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: Even if the signatures of the interfaces are the same, for the interpreter they are not. They both need to implement the same (same signature/namespace) interface. Seeing as they have no idea of each other they can't. So one would have to _hack_ their code by at least chainging a `use Foo\IDoSomething as IDoSomething` statement in one place. Having each class/interface in a file helps a lot.

Comment: _They don't._ means what you are asking for is not possible.